# Не работает console.log

Tags: javascript, html

На двух сайтах с одинаковым кодом на одном позиция скрола выводится в консоль, а на втором нет. `alert` в это время работает там и там.

Вот код:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let scrollPos = window.scrollY;
    console.log (scrollPos);
});
```

Возможно нужно указывать что-то в html-коде, кроме `<script src="script.js"></script>`?

Comment: Скорее всего мы здесь ничем не поможем, потому как не знаем чем отличается один сайт от другого. Еще раз перепроверьте код на том сайте, где не работает.

Comment: Где не выводится - ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: Где не работает? Вы уверены что

Comment: @InDevX Консоль пустая

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте указать код в html теге `<script>`.

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let scrollPos = window.scrollY;
    console.log (scrollPos);
});
</script>
```

Comment: не работает, консоль по прежнему пустая

Comment: @Wumpy можете скинуть ссылку на сайт?

Comment: к сожалению нет, у меня нет хостинга, это мой второй сайт в жизни. Я даже не знаю как работать с хостингами. Если только есть другой способ

Comment: @Wumpy вы можете запустить сайт в песочнице типа jsfiddle.net или codepen.io, добавив свой html, css и js код

Comment: https://codepen.io/Wumpy13/pen/RwVLeZM (если у вас найдётся время для критики html и css кода, я с радостью её прочитал бы)

Comment: @Wumpy вот в песочнице у вас работает запись в консоль, по поводу css - я не знаю для чего вы пишите код. Я увидел верстку для экранов более 1000px, если Вы хотите поддерживать меньшие экраны, то кода недостаточно для ревью.